# How to derive this variance $VAR(S) = \frac{1}{18} \Big( n(n-1)(2n+5) - \sum_{k=1}^p q_k(q_k-1)(2q_k+5) \Big)$, in Mann-Kendall Test

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

When I read this doc [Mann-Kendall Test (mkt)](https://up-rs-esp.github.io/mkt/), I am curious how this formula is derived
$VAR(S) = \frac{1}{18} \Big( n(n-1)(2n+5) - \sum_{k=1}^p q_k(q_k-1)(2q_k+5) \Big)$

The original text is as follows：

The Mann-Kendall test is used to determine whether or not there is a linear monotonic trend in a given time series data.

......

The first step in the Mann-Kendall test for a time series $x_1, x_2,
\dots, x_n$ of length n is to compute the indicator function $sgn(x_i - x_j)$ such that:

\begin{split}sgn(x_i - x_j) &=
    \begin{cases}
                    1,  & x_i - x_j > 0\\
                    0,  & x_i - x_j = 0\\
                    -1, & x_i - x_j < 0
    \end{cases},\end{split}

which tells us whether the difference between the measurements at time $i$ and $j$ are positive, negative or zero.

Next, we compute the mean and variance of the above quantity. The mean $E[S]$ is given by:

$E[S] = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} sgn(x_i - x_j),$

and the variance $VAR(S)$ is given by:

$VAR(S) = \frac{1}{18} \Big( n(n-1)(2n+5) - \sum_{k=1}^p
q_k(q_k-1)(2q_k+5) \Big),$

where $p$ is the total number of tie groups in the data, and $q_k$ is the number of data points contained in the $k$-th tie group. For example, if the time series measurements were {12, 56, 23, 12, 67, 45, 56, 56, 10}, we would have two tie groups for the measurements 12 and 56, i.e. $p$=2, and the number of data points in these tie groups would $q_1$=2 for the tie group with {12}, and $q_2$=3 for the tie group with {56}.

......

Comment: Please use MathJax by adding `$$...$$` before equations.

Comment: What is $S$? If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are time ordered observations, then the Mann test of trend is based on $T=\binom{n}{2}^{-1}\sum_{1\le i<j\le n} \operatorname{sgn}(X_j-X_i)$ (related to Kendall's sample $\tau$ coefficient). Mean and variance of $T$ can be obtained using standard properties of U-statistic or otherwise, for which you can refer to *Nonparametric Statistical Inference* by Gibbons and Chakraborty.

Comment: The linked website is not a good source for exploring the theoretical aspects of this test. Check out the source of the formula given below in the website.